# Code to print a diamond with a given length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iteration

So I am currently learning JavaScript and I am interested in the many different ways one can accomplish something in programming. This is my diamond code, which will work with a given odd number:

```
const l = 11;
let space = ' '; 
let star = '*';
let i = 1;
let k;
let n = 0;

while(i <= l) {
  k = (l - i)/2;
  console.log(space.repeat(k) + star.repeat(i));
  i = i + 2;
}

// i = i - 2;

while(i >= 2) {
  i = i - 2;
  k = (l - i)/2;
  if(i < l) {                       // To get rid of repeating middle line
    console.log(space.repeat(k) + star.repeat(i));
  } else { 
    continue; 
    }
}
```

Are there any other more intuitive ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Iterative Approach

If you wanted to use an iterative approach to solving this, you could do:

```js
const makeDiamond = n => {
   let total = n, iter = 0
   const base = ['*'.repeat(n)] // Start with the middle, build out
   while((n-=2) > 0) {
      const layer = ' '.repeat(++iter)+'*'.repeat(n)
      base.unshift(layer) // Prepend layer
      base.push(layer)    // Append layer
   }
   base.forEach(l => console.log(l)) // Print each layer in sequence
}

makeDiamond(11);
```

Note: this works for diamonds of even or odd sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a recursive approach and call the function until you got the longest star line.

```js
function diamond(l, i = 1) {
    const
        STAR = '*',
        SPACE = ' ',
        LINE = SPACE.repeat((l - i) / 2) + STAR.repeat(i);

    console.log(LINE);
    if (i >= l) return;
    diamond(l, i + 2);
    console.log(LINE);
}

diamond(11);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to make the nth line.
Create the top by creating an array equal half the height and map it with the line function.
Join the top, then reverse the top and use that as the bottom.

```js
const diamond=n=>(n=Array(~~(n/2)).fill().map((v,i)=>" ".repeat((n-i*2+1)/2)+"*".repeat(i*2+1))).join("\n")+"\n"+n.reverse().slice(1).join("\n");
console.log(diamond(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

with `reduce`:

```js
const n = 11;
Array.from(Array(~-n/2|0), (_,i) => " ".repeat(i+1) + "*".repeat(n+~i*2))
  .reduce((a, c) => [c, ...a, c], ["*".repeat(n)])
  .forEach(l=>console.log(l))
```

`~-n/2|0 === Math.floor((n-1)/2)`

`n+~i*2 === n-(i+1)*2`

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to create another similar code that keeps i = i + 2 going instead of decreasing it in the second loop.

```
const l = 11;
let space = ' '; 
let star = '*';
let i = 1;
let k;
let n = 0;

while(i <= l) {
  k = (l - i)/2;
  console.log(space.repeat(k) + star.repeat(i));
  i = i + 2;
}

while(i >= l) {
  k = (i - l)/2;
  n = i - (4 * k);
  if (n > 0) {console.log(space.repeat(k) + star.repeat(n));
  } else { break; }
  i = i + 2;
}
```